# FancyBox gallery integration

Tags: jquery, fancybox, gallery, thumbnails, hidden

I have a question regarding the integration of FancyBox.
I would create a gallery with 10 pictures but only one thumbnail.
For example:
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/
The first demonstration shows four images : forest, sea, sunset and Effeil tower.
Can I include a single thumbnail, for example a thumbnail of the Eiffel Tower, which on clicked, would display the image of the Eiffel Tower in the lightbox, but also those of the forest, sea and sunset.
I tried many things but nothing works properly.
If you have any ideas...
Many Thanks.

PS:
I use the Twitter Bootstrap-1.3 & FancyBox-2

Answer (score 6):

You need a link to all the images in your gallery regardless they show a thumbnail or not so you may have this html

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="image01.jpg"><img src="thumbnail01.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="image02.jpg"></a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="image03.jpg"></a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="image04.jpg"></a>
```

etc. ... in that way, only a single thumbnail is shown and the rest of the links are not visible but functional.

Then a script like this will fire the gallery

```
$("a.fancybox").fancybox();
```

Comment: But with Twitter Bootstsrap, the <a> tag keep a "small space" in the media-grid even if they have no items to display. And it breaks the layout... I tried to change the Bootstrap CSS but the "invisible space" seems impossible to remove.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add display:none to the links you don't want to show.

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/MvvuE/

Comment: Yes I tried that. Maybe I made a mistake but it did not resolve my problem. With the Twitter Bootstrap, the <a> tag keep a "small space" in the media-grid even if they have no items to display. Despite my low level in javascript I even tried to create a fonction to hide an id fancybox but I finally got a response from the fancybox team and apparently I tried to do too complicated.

Comment: <a href="1.jpg" rel="gallery"><img /></a>
<div style="display:none;">
    <a href="2.jpg" rel="gallery"><img /></a>
    <a href="3.jpg" rel="gallery"><img /></a>
</div>

Comment: That is ok and really simple to applicate :)