# fancybox pass array of images but start with displaying what was clicked

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I've been playing around with fancybox today and to a point I've got it working. 
I am able to pass a single image or an array of images. But what I can't seem to do is have both.

So what I want is to click the thumbnail. That will load but then the next and previous buttons in the popup will the cycle the array of images that was also passed.

When I try to do both then the popup just cycles the first thumbnail that was clicked but does display a different image title on each cycle.

I've gone through quite a few of the post on here already today, testing out various bits of code but still unable to make this work.

You can see my issue here: http://www.scotflash.co.uk/website/pages/latest/latest.php

Below is my code.

```
$('.flckrimage').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    parent.$.fancybox([<?php echo getGallery('34089471@N08',12); ?>],{
        href: this.href,
        type: 'image'
    }); 
});
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly you are trying to create a gallery from the flicker images you have loaded there.

In that case, how about using FancyBox's built in gallery feature. This can be used by adding a common 'rel="gallery_name"' to the links in the markup.

Here's what it might look like:

http://jsfiddle.net/v3CAR/15/

HTML:

```
<a href="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3714/9554519784_66e130a6b0_b.jpg" title="background_6" rel="gallery" class="flckrimage">
    <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3714/9554519784_66e130a6b0_s.jpg" alt="background_6" title="background_6" class="flickrimg">
    </a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('.flckrimage').click(function (e) {
        $('.flckrimage').fancybox();

    });

});
```

This thread might be of help as well: [FancyBox gallery integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136888/fancybox-gallery-integration)

Comment: Hi, What you have given me does work if I am NOT pulling the page into an iframe on the main site. When I view the page from the main site it displays the gallery within the iframe. I want fancybox to appear over the main site. You can see where I am at just now here: http://www.scotflash.co.uk/website/  Thanks for you help and any further assistance.

Comment: @PaulBainbridge, how about this: `$('.flckrimage').click(function(e){ 
              
              e.preventDefault();
            console.log("href:"+this.href);
            
            parent.$('.flckrimage').fancybox({
             type: 'image',
             
             }); 
         
             });`

Comment: Hi nef. Sorry but that did nothing. I've updated the page on the site so that you can see if there is anything that I've missed.